# How to seal these sewer clean outs?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, sewer

I have these caps just outside of my house that I’m assuming are sewer clean outs. The problem is the pipe is all corroded and the caps are PVC that are just set on top of it. They don’t seal as there are no more threads.

Do I have to completely dig out the access and replace with PVC, or is there another way to attach to the metal and seal near the surface?

What’s the best way to remediate this so I have a seal?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same cast iron double cleanout, but the threads on mine are not as corroded as yours.  In your case the simplest solution would be to clean up the threads as much as you feel like with a wire brush and then use an internal expanding plug which does not need threads.

A step further would be to get the right size tap and recut the threads to allow the PVC or ABS threaded plug to screw in. You can use silicone grease on the threads.

You could also investigate how hard it would be to remove the inner cast iron part with the threads. It appears that this is pressed in with a rubber seal. However, if you would do this, you had better be sure that you don't pull the cleanout out at the bottom.

EDIT

Google: Real-Tite® Reusable Expansion Cleanout Plugs/Covers

Comment: Thanks for this info, I wasn’t familiar with internal expanding plugs so that’s very helpful.

Comment: Use a plug with a flange on one end which is larger than the inside dia of the hole so it can't fall in. If you are using a wire brush manually or on a drill, there is always the possibility of dropping it down inside. It might be best to not worry about existing corrosion. Just get the right size and type of plug, smear on silicone grease and snug it. Doesn't have to be tight.

Comment: Great advice. I’m planning to redo this flower bed and turn it into a flagstone patio. I’d like thes access points to be below grade so I’m thinking about cutting off the pipe a few inches below the ground, grinding the cut smooth, and sealing it with this. Do you see issues with that plan?

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-4-in-Gripper-Mechanical-Plastic-Test-Plug-33403D/100204964?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&mtc=Shopping-B-F_D26P-G-D26P-26_1_PIPE_AND_FITTINGS-NA-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-PIPE_AND_FITTINGS_General&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D26P-G-D26P-26_1_PIPE_AND_FITTINGS-NA-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-PIPE_AND_FITTINGS_General-71700000052572890-58700005047670158-92700047360240758&gclid=CjwKCAjwkdL6BRAREiwA-kiczJ_YL-7AeKZ3Jf237fDca6geSm78O8PJJ7xxqE9KFKEQzL35YCF4dxoCBJMQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: You don't want these to be below ground. I replaced our original brass caps with screw in black plastic that had a recessed wrench fitting instead of the raised wrench flats. The brass were corroded stuck and had to be cut and deformed by a plumber to insert a camera.

Comment: I thought these might be in an out of the way location. Since they are not I would not use the internal expanding plug because the wing nut and bolt would be in the way. I strongly discourage cutting off this fitting. You can get a black plastic screw in fitting which you can walk on which will not be an eyesore. These cleanouts must be accessible.

Comment: Google "flush cleanout plugs polypropylene" or "flush cleanout plugs brass". I think these are usually 3 inch nominal. Polypropylene or ABS or PVC will never stick from corrosion, especially if you apply silicone grease on assembly.

Comment: Google Real-Tite® Reusable Expansion Cleanout Plugs/Covers . These should be ideal.

Comment: Ok thank you, those look perfect. These threads are about 2 inches higher than the cement porch they are next to. I was hoping to have the flagstone flush with the cement which is why I wanted to cut off these fittings. If I cut these off flush with the new grade and install these ( link below) would that be acceptable so these don’t stick up higher than the flagstone?

Comment: https://www.diydirectsupply.com/Park-Supply-of-America-REAL-TITE-Pipe-Plug-Expander?gclid=CjwKCAjwkdL6BRAREiwA-kiczBOt2u4OZBt7GDJpJ6pLIVY_u1HaOjLlbGJ_X6DyKh5Wc5gjcD2TgBoC3RMQAvD_BwE

Comment: You may have what is called a 3 inch not a 4 inch.  The diameter at the threads of one of my nominal 3" screw in plugs is 3-3/8 inch. What is the diameter of the loose one of your plugs? What does it indicate on the plug? Someone else is going to have to weigh in on whether it would be advisable to cut off that cast iron fitting.

Comment: There is a special cutter for cast iron sewer pipe that cuts by fracturing. Hardened steel wheels are progressively tightened around the cast iron pipe until it fractures from pressure. Rent one if you are going to cut this.

Comment: Jim, great advice. It's a 3". ID is 3.25" and the PVC cap says 3". Good looking out! I ordered 2x Test-tite IPS 83688 3-Inch Flush Mechanical Cleanout Repair Plug. My thought is it will seal the pipe as is, or if i cut off the fitting i can seal the pipe where i make the cut with this same plug as the ID of the pipe is consistent all the way down. For now i'll seal as is and wait and think more about cutting it off first, maybe see how it looks with some flagstone around it. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

A common approach is a rubber coupling (also called a "Fernco®" for the same reason adhesive bandages are called "Band-Aids®")

Counter-intuitively, the last time I read the instructions carefully the ones with a stainless steel reinforcement (sheilded) were not recommended for burial and the plain rubber ones (unsheilded) (with stainless steel clamps) were, but read the instructions carefully yourself to be sure.

General approach is to cut off the iron pipe and use a rubber fitting to transition to PVC. Then be sure to protect the PVC from sunlight (cover it in some way, or at the least paint it. Sunlight is not good for PVC pipe.) You may need to use a wire brush and/or grinder to get the outside of the iron pipe smooth enough for a good seal.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Would you recommend making the cuts with an angle grinder or a metal cutting blade on a circular saw?

Comment: Will sunlight actually damage a cleanout significantly? I see unpainted PVC cleanouts in areas exposed to sun all the time and haven't ever seen one that appeared damaged. A quick search turned up that sunlight discolors PVC and [reduces its impact resistance](https://www.heritageplastics.com/technical-bulletins/effect-sunlight-exposure-pvc-pipe-conduit-fittings/) but doesn't seem to affect any other material properties.